# Preloader плавный переход

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь реализовать плавный прелоадер на странице,

добавляю новый класс который плавно скрывает пейлоадер,

```js
document.body.onload = function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var preloader = document.getElementById('loader-wrapper');
    if (!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
      preloader.classList.add('done')
    }
  }, 3000)
}
```

```css
.done {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

после прохождения пейлоадера загруженная страница не доступна к взаимодействию,
пробовал добавить `display: none` это решает вопрос с взаимодействием, но, не применяется анимация плавности,
Просьба, подсказать как можно решить данный вопрос

Comment: Анимировать можно только те свойства, значения которых непрерывны (т.е., когда между начальным и конечным значениями есть промежуточные). Свойства `display`и `visibility` к таким не относятся. Используй оверлей с анимацией `opacity`, например (последнее у тебя уже прописано в стилях, поэтому может быть будет достаточно из них убрать неанимируемые. Если недостаточно - то либо переделывать на keyframes-анимацию, либо добавлять еще один класс с `display: none;` после завершения анимации).

Comment: @yar85 благодарю за подсказку, создал новый класс с none и по очереди добавил их, интервал none сделал чуть больше чем у блока с transition, удалось реализовать плавное затухание и работу со страницей

Comment: [Вот базовый пример с `animation`](https://jsbin.com/benitolotu/edit?html,output), если что (в ответ не получится - пишу с планшетника, и местные кодсниппеты поломаны)... задержка через `await` там добавлена для симуляции долгой загрузки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно добавить селектор статуса, сделать анимацию, и с js по animationend-событию переключать display. Или на любителя, через transitionend

```
const animated = document.querySelector('.animOpacity');

    animated.onanimationend = () => {
    className.classList.remove('animOpacity')
};
```